# What does this line mean in matlab? Simple implementation of Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, dijkstra

This is an implementation of Dijkstra algorithm. if `Distance = Inf*ones(N,1)` , what is the value of `Distance(CurrentNode)`?? And could someone also give an example value of src and ConMat? Thank you!

```
while (nVisited <N)
   Visited(CurrentNode) = 1;
   for i=1:N
       if (ConMat(CurrentNode,i)>0)
           temp = ConMat(CurrentNode,i) + **Distance(CurrentNode)**;
           if (temp< Distance(i))
               Distance(i) = temp;
               PrevNode(i) = CurrentNode;
           end
       end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distance = Inf * ones(N,1)` returns

```
Inf
Inf
Inf

...
Inf
```

an array with size *Nx1*.

---

`CurrentNode` contains the index of the vertice your algorithm is computing the path. Suppose you have a simple graph, such as the following (stolen from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)):

[image]

Your initial `src` is the node you start your search – in this case, index `1`. For your initial node, `Distance` is `0`. So, `Distance( 1 ) = 0`, while the others has `Distance` equals to `Inf` (`Distance(src+1:end) = Inf`).

---

`ConMat` is your graph in a matrix representation.

Answer (score 1):

distance is an array of length n where n is the number of nodes.  distance(i) is the best found distance from src to node i. all distances start at infinity but distance(src) starts at 0. then we update the distances